# Infinite scrolling in both directions - Up and down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I am trying to create a page that is an endless scrolling loop both up and down.

At the moment I am using jquery to relocate content from the top of the page to the bottom. This creates a nice seemless loop when you scroll down but I would like it to work when the user scrolls up too.

The problem seems to be that even if content is positioned in negative vertical space on the page the scroll will not extend to that space. As far as I am aware there is no way to override this so I am looking for some type of work around.

I have thoughts of using javascript to disable the scrolling and using the scroll event to reposition the elements but there are already lots of absolute positioned elements and animation happening on the page so I'm concerned about performance taking that route.

Any other leads?

Comment: Hello. I would like to know how did you implement the scrolling loop you already have. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any other leads?

Seen these?

[5 jQuery infinite Scrolling Demos](http://www.jquery4u.com/tutorials/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/)

[jsfiddle that I cannot find origin of.](http://jsfiddle.net/27s5y/) (I didn't write and don't know who did)

Comment: None of those have infinite scroll both up and down.

Answer (score 4):

OK... I worked it out.

I adapted [this script](http://jsfiddle.net/27s5y/) which instantly relocates the scroll location to the top of the page when you get to the bottom and to the bottom when you reach the top.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= 18830 ) {
        $(window).scrollTop(201);
    }
    else if ( $(window).scrollTop() == 0 ) {
        $(window).scrollTop(18629);
    }    
});
```

And then I made sure that the content at the bottom and the top of the page was identical. I thought that there would be a flash or something when this relocation happened but it's smooth!

Comment: "I wrote this script" Do you realise this is the same code that's in the fiddle I posted?

Comment: oh sorry. I just noticed this. I didn't intentionally try to trick people in to thinking it was me that wrote the script from scratch. It was an honest mistake.

Answer (score 3):

The solution I like the best is [this one](http://www.jquery4u.com/demos/infinite-scrolling-demo3/) ([code](http://www.jquery4u.com/tutorials/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/#d_clip_container_4)), because it adds elements at the bottom *before* the bottom is reached, making sure that scrolling remains continuous (even with [smooth](https://plus.google.com/116164717430356367649/posts/9rCL4QwMbqf) [scrolling](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/928979) on). However, it doesn't work that well on mobile phones where scrolling can happen pretty quickly. I recommend Marijn Haverbeke's [wonderful article](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/blog/a-pathological-scrolling-model.html) on fake scrollbars in CodeMirror where he deals with similar issues.

I leave you with some snippets.

> First, some background. Why would we want to fake a scrollbar to begin with?
>
> In order to remain responsive when huge documents are loaded in, CodeMirror does not render the whole document, but only the part of it that is currently scrolled into view. This means that the amount of DOM nodes it creates is limited by the size of the viewport, and the browser relayouts triggered by changes to the text are relatively cheap.

And further down...

> Then, it listens to wheel events, but never calls preventDefault on them or does scrolling in response to them. Instead, it responds by setting a timeout to observe the amount of pixels that the wheel event did scroll the content, and uses that to tweak its delta-to-pixel rate at run-time.

Answer (score 2):

Clone your HTML body two (or three) times (in javascript or otherwise). Start the page in the middle copy instead of the top, and then you can handle scrolling however you like.

Comment: hmm... but scrolling beyond the top:0px position seems to be impossible even if you do have elements placed beyond that point.

Comment: You won't be using that syntax any more. Set aside your method for a second and just imagine a simple, JS-free page with a few HTML elements. Clone the contents. Scroll to the end of the first copy (start of the second). Can you not scroll up and down?

Comment: Once the user starts scrolling, then you start moving data from bottom to top. But since you're not starting from the top, the user won't hit the scroll limit.

Answer (score 1):

As many have suggested, if your page doesn't look exactly the same at the top and at the bottom you’ll need to clone your content to make it look like it does. I’ve made an example using this technique that works pretty smooth:

```js
/*
Ininite looping scroll.
Tested and works well in latest Chrome, Safari and Firefox.
*/

(function (window) {
  'use strict';

  var doc = document,
    body = doc.body,
    html = doc.documentElement,
    startElement = doc.getElementsByClassName('is-start')[0],
    clones = doc.getElementsByClassName('is-clone'),
    disableScroll = false,
    docHeight,
    scrollPos,
    clonesHeight,
    i;

  function getScrollPos() {
    return (window.pageYOffset || html.scrollTop)  - (html.clientTop || 0);
  }

  function getDocHeight() {
    return Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);
  }

  function getClonesHeight() {
    i = 0;
    clonesHeight = 0;

    for (i; i < clones.length; i += 1) {
      clonesHeight = clonesHeight + clones[i].offsetHeight;
    }

    return clonesHeight;
  }

  docHeight = getDocHeight();
  clonesHeight = getClonesHeight();

  window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    scrollPos = getScrollPos();
    docHeight = getDocHeight();
    clonesHeight = getClonesHeight();

    if (scrollPos <= 0) {
      window.scroll(0, 1); // Scroll 1 pixel to allow upwards scrolling.
    }
  }, false);

  window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    if (disableScroll === false) {
      scrollPos = getScrollPos();

      if (clonesHeight + scrollPos >= docHeight) {
        // Scroll to the top when you’ve reached the bottom
        window.scroll(0, 1); // Scroll 1 pixel to allow upwards scrolling.
        disableScroll = true;
      } else if (scrollPos <= 0) {
        // Scroll to the top of the clones when you reach the top.
        window.scroll(0, docHeight - clonesHeight);
        disableScroll = true;
      }

      if (disableScroll) {
        // Disable scroll-repositioning for a while to avoid flickering.
        window.setTimeout(function () {
          disableScroll = false;
        }, 100);
      }
    }
  }, false);

  // Needs a small delay in some browsers.
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    if (startElement) {
      // Start at the middle of the starting block.
      window.scroll(0, Math.round(startElement.getBoundingClientRect().top + document.body.scrollTop - (window.innerHeight - startElement.offsetHeight) / 2));
    } else {
      // Scroll 1 pixel to allow upwards scrolling.
      window.scroll(0, 1);
    }
  });

}(this));
```

```css
section {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  height: 80vh;
}

.red {
  background: #FF4136;
}
.green {
  background: #2ECC40;
}
.blue {
  background: #0074D9;
}
.orange {
  background: rebeccapurple;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;

  font-size: 5vw;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

body {
  font-family: "Avenir Next", Montserrat, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 100%;
}

::scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="green">
  <h1>One</h1>
</section>
<section class="red">
  <h1>For</h1>
</section>
<section class="blue">
  <h1>All</h1>
</section>
<section class="orange">
  <h1>And</h1>
</section>
<section class="blue">
  <h1>All</h1>
</section>
<section class="red">
  <h1>For</h1>
</section>

<!--
These following blocks are the same as the first blocks to get that looping illusion going. You need to add clones to fill out a full viewport height.
-->
<section class="green is-clone is-start">
  <h1>One</h1>
</section>
<section class="red is-clone">
  <h1>For</h1>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Building up on Mahmoud's answer, I hacked up this in a few minutes.

It works somewhat (at least on Firefox) when scrolling either with keys or with mouse wheel, but it gets all glitchy when dragging the scrollbar. Depending on how the `div` heights relate to the viewport height, all kinds of fireworks can happen too.

Still, I hope this can help you get on the right direction.

```
function onScroll(){
    var SAFETY_MARGIN = 50,
        scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop(),
        docHeight = $(document.body).height(),
        winHeight = $(window).height(),
        firstDiv = $('body>div:first-child')[0],
        lastDiv = $('body>div:last-child')[0],
        lowerLimit = SAFETY_MARGIN,
        higherLimit = docHeight - SAFETY_MARGIN;

    // Scrolling too high
    if( scrollPos <= lowerLimit ){

        // Move content to top;
        $(lastDiv).prependTo(document.body);

        // Adjust scroll position to compensate
        // for the new content at the top
        $(window).scrollTop(scrollPos + $(lastDiv).height());

    }

    // Scrolling too low
    else if( scrollPos + winHeight >= higherLimit ){

        // Move content to bottom
        $(firstDiv).appendTo(document.body);

        // Adjust scroll position to compensate
        // for the missing content at the top
        $(window).scrollTop(scrollPos - $(firstDiv).height());
    } 
}


$(window).scroll(onScroll);

$(window).load(function(){
    var $body = $(document.body);
    $(window).scrollTop($body.height() / 2);
});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div style="height: 600px; background-color: red">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="height: 600px; background-color: green">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="height: 600px; background-color: blue">&nbsp;</div>

</body>
</html>
```